# Combining two plots with different domains into one

Tags: plotting

How can I combine the following two plots in one figure:

```
Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}]
```

and

```
Plot[1/x^3, {x, 1, ∞}]
```

Comment: Does `Plot[1/x^3, {x, 1, \[Infinity]}]` produce an output for you?

Comment: @JasonB. It works for me but maybe because I have a 65 inch monitor. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Piecewise` to put two functions together if they have different domains.

```
Plot[
 Piecewise[{
   {x, 0 <= x <= 1},
   {1/x^3, 1 < x < \[Infinity]}
   }],
 {x, 0, 10},
 PlotRange -> Full
]
```

[image: Piecewise display of x and 1/x^3.]

Comment: Or `f[x_ /; 0 <= x <= 1] := x;
f[x_ /; x > 1] := 1/x^3;

Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]`

Comment: @BobHanlon That's very cool. I didn't know you could do that.